# Changing a form opacity from a custom timer class

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a class that inherits a timer class because I want to customize the Tick function, and I want to use this specific function in many classes without the need to change the function in all the timers every time.

```
Public Class FadeInTimer
Inherits Timer

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    Me.Enabled = False
    Me.Interval = 75
End Sub

Private Sub FadeInTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Tick
    Dim workingAreaWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
    Me.Opacity += 0.1

    If Not Me.Location.X <= workingAreaWidth Then
        Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X - 30, Me.Location.Y)
    End If

    Me.Refresh()
    If Me.Opacity = 1 Then
        Me.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The purpose of this function is to make a simple fade in when the form is created. The problem is I can't use "Me." because I am in the Timer class, so, how can I make changes to the form from this class.

Comment: You need a reference to the form object, pass it through the constructor.  You can't let it increment to 1.0, that will flicker like a cheap motel.  0.99 is the maximum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to pass an instance of the form to be faded in inside the constructor of the custom timer, save that instance in a global class variable and add the tick handler with *AddHandler* like so

```
Public Class FadeInTimer
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Dim parent As Form

    Public Sub New(p As Form)
        MyBase.New()
        parent = p
        AddHandler MyBase.Tick, AddressOf FadeInTimer_Tick 

    End Sub
```

Now, when you need to refer to the 'parent' form you use the *parent* variable and not the *Me* statement. Also, every time you need to refer to the timer, you should use *MyBase* statement

```
Private Sub FadeInTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    Dim workingAreaWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Parent.Width
    parent.Opacity += 0.1

    If Not parent.Location.X <= workingAreaWidth Then
        parent.Location = New Point(parent.Location.X - 30, parent.Location.Y)
    End If

    parent.Refresh()
    If parent.Opacity = 1 Then
        MyBase.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

This could be tested in LinqPad using this code

```
Sub Main
    Dim f As Form = New Form()
    Dim t As FadeInTimer = New FadeInTimer(f)

    f.Opacity = 0
    t.Interval = 150
    t.Start()
    f.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```